# How can I track Google Analytics Across Multiple Domains in one account google?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I have installed Google Analytics on my website. The website is `www.myhospitals.com`. When the user clicks button A, it will track on Google Analytics. When the user clicks button B, it will also track on Google Analytics

But I want to add a new domain / new sub domain. The name is `www.career.myhospitals.com`

Can I add the domain on google analytics to one Google account? or I have to create a new account to track on that domain?

Comment: and please do not tag languages that are irrelevant!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same account for that...

Follow the steps

1. Click on the Admin at the bottom of the page

[image]

2. Now click on Add Property in the middle of the page.

[image]

3. Now select Web and complete the setup :-)

[image]

Hoping this would help you